Ceiling fan with light and remote and two wall switches
Ceiling has blk white red and bare
Fan has white blue grey yellow red
Receiver has blk white input
Output has grey yellow red blue white
How do I wire it

Do you have the instructions for the fan?  Whites should be neutrals unless you have an old style switch loop, so pictures of the switch wiring will be useful.  White and sometimes grey should be neutral, bare or green are ground, most other colours are hot/switch hots.  Wiring diagram, paper or online, for the fan is required.  Are the two switches one for the fan and one for the light, or three way switches at different doors/entrances?

Try this answer https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/310989/157970
